# MariaDB 10.2 Xtrabackup. /usr//bin/wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 WSREP_SST_OPT_PORT: unbound variable

Tags: mariadb

I just installed a new set of Ubuntu 16.04 nodes which should work as MariaDB 10.2 master-master cluster, using XtraBackup as SST method.

The first node comes up fine with the command galera_new_cluster, but the second node is unable to join the cluster due to the following error :

```
Nov 15 10:59:09 mariadb10 mysqld[15664]: 2017-11-15 10:59:09 140259808827136 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
Nov 15 10:59:09 mariadb10 mysqld[15664]: 2017-11-15 10:59:09 140259416360704 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'joiner' --address '10.0.0.10' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'   --parent '15664' --binlog '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin' '
Nov 15 10:59:09 mariadb10 mysqld[15664]: /usr//bin/wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2: line 646: WSREP_SST_OPT_PORT: unbound variable
Nov 15 10:59:09 mariadb10 mysqld[15664]: 2017-11-15 10:59:09 140259416360704 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read 'ready <addr>' from: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'joiner' --address '10.0.0.10' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'   --parent '15664' --binlog '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin'
Nov 15 10:59:09 mariadb10 mysqld[15664]: #011Read: '(null)'
Nov 15 10:59:09 mariadb10 mysqld[15664]: 2017-11-15 10:59:09 140259416360704 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2 --role 'joiner' --address '10.0.0.10' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'   --parent '15664' --binlog '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin' : 1 (Operation not permitted)
Nov 15 10:59:09 mariadb10 mysqld[15664]: 2017-11-15 10:59:09 140259808827136 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to prepare for 'xtrabackup-v2' SST. Unrecoverable.
```

Main issue in this piece of logging is the WSREP_SST_OPT_PORT which is not set.

Looking at the code of `/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2` it "include" the `/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_common` in which the variable can be set in 2 ways.

1. Using the `--port` commandline parameter.
2. Using a port in the `--address` commandline parameter (ip:port)

Since I have now clue what parameters mariadb is using to fill the command line parameters for the `/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2`, I also don't know how to let it use the `--port` or `--address` with the correct value.

I did already play around with some parameters in the my.cnf for mariadb without any result. The things I tried were :

- Adding parameter `wsrep_sst_opt_port=4444` to `my.cnf`. This resulted in an error since the parameter is not supported (but hey.. the best solutions were the result of just trying)
- Added ports to the addresses in `wsrep_cluster_adress`. This was accepted, but did not result in a portnumber being part of the `--address` parameter.
- Added port to the address in `wsrep_node_address`. This also was accepted, but did also not reuslt in a portnumber in the `--address` parameter.

As a workaround I did adapt the `/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_common` and I added the following code (starting after the comment) :

```
if [ -n "${WSREP_SST_OPT_ADDR_PORT:-}" ]; then
  if [ -n "${WSREP_SST_OPT_PORT:-}" ]; then
...
  else
    readonly WSREP_SST_OPT_PORT="$WSREP_SST_OPT_ADDR_PORT"
  fi
fi

# Start of the workaround
if [ -z "${WSREP_SST_OPT_PORT:-}" ]; then
  readonly WSREP_SST_OPT_PORT="4444"
fi
# End of the workaround
```

This at least solved my non-starting cluster, but it would still be nice to know how I can let it work without this workaround...

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you experience is actually a bug in MariaDB 10.2.10 and the MariaDB team has come up with a fix that will most probably be released in the near future

This is the link to the issue on the MariaDB bug tracker:

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14256